# Behaviour of Cygwin's `(no)dosfilewarning`

Tags: cygwin

### Original Question

Cygwin's `CYGWIN` environment variable and its contents have effect on several aspects of the Cygwin environment. If `CYGWIN` contains `nodosfilewarning` then

> Cygwin will warn the **first time** a user uses an "MS-DOS" style path name rather than a POSIX-style path name

as stated by one of Cygwin [FAQ pages](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html).

What is *first time*? Once a day? Once between computer restarts?

I had set `CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning`, but still *sometimes* Cygwin warns me that I use MS-DOS style paths. If I set it to `dosfilewarning` (and restart my shell) I can't trigger the warning no matter what (like `cd C:\\Windows`—I assume this is *MS-DOS-ish* enough).

I don't exactly know if the `CYGWIN` variable have to be set at OS level or in my Cygwin shell, however I have tried both without success. By *without success* I mean, if the variable is set to `dosfilewarning` my assumption is that Cygwin should warn me every time I type something like `cd C:\\Windows` (which it doesn't do).

How can I verify that I set this stupid variable correctly and my settings are in effect? Cygwin's FAQ gives little help on this particular problem.

### Update

Thanks to [JdeBP](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp)'s answer I've managed to come to the following conclusion.

The `CYGWIN` variable can be set either at OS level or in a Cygwin shell.

`cd C:\\Windows` doesn't trigger the warning at hand, but `ls C:\\Windows` does (talk about consistency, huh?).

For now, settings `nodosfilewarning` really reports no warning for the previously mentioned command, however I originally wrote this post because even though I told Cygwin not to report these warnings it still did sometimes. Unfortunately I don't know when and under what circumstances (I'll update the question if I further encounter these warnings).

Comment: `cd` is not a program, but a command of the shell. Probably related to that.

Comment: @DanielBeck You're right, but I think one would still expect to trigger the warning nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every process that uses the Cygwin runtime library maps into that process a portion of shared memory.  This contains some data that are shared across all processes using (that particular installation of) the Cygwin runtime library.

One of the flags in that shared memory is the `warned_msdos` flag.  If the `warned_msdos` flag is `false`, and if `dosfilewarning` is set in the `CYGWIN` environment variable that the process had at process initialization, then you will see the warning.  When the warning is issued, the `warned_msdos` flag is set to `true`.

Note, importantly:

- The check won't be made in the first place by any process that had `nodosfilewarning`.
- If the check isn't made, `warned_msdos` will remain set to `false`.
- The shared memory stays around until all Cygwin processes using it terminate.